# How to set next month when reach max days in date input

Tags: html, date

When I click on an increment arrow when max days is set I want to go to the first day of the next month, not first day same month.

```html
<input type="date" value="2017-01-31">
```

```
2017-01-31
```

When i click next day:

```
 2017-02-01
```

Comment: You need JavaScript. What did you try? jQuery UI can possibly provide you with a more customisable datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this , you can use more easier and customisable datepicker which easy to use and have many options .look at the link below:-

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/